# Parsing XML from a URL address and converting into a table using PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to take the following xml from this url http://r7j8v4x4.map2.ssl.hwcdn.net/NOD_R.xml and make a table with the data.  I've verified I can pull the data by using print_r($xml); but I can't get the data to dump into the table.  This is what I've got so far, which is probably wrong.  Can anyone help me out with the proper code to use?

```
<?php
$url = "http://r7j8v4x4.map2.ssl.hwcdn.net/NOD_R.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <col><span style="font-weight:bold">Day</span></col>
  &nbsp;
  &nbsp;

  <col><span style="font-weight:bold">Time(Eastern)</span></col>
  &nbsp;
  &nbsp;
  <col><span style="font-weight:bold">Reservoir Elev. (behind dam)*</span</col>
  &nbsp;
  &nbsp;
  <col><span style="font-weight:bold">Tailwater Elev. (below dam)*</span></col>
  &nbsp;
  &nbsp;
  <col><span style="font-weight:bold">Avg Hourly Discharge*</span></col>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php foreach ($xml->RESULTSET->ROW as $obs) :?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $obs->obs_day; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $obs->obs_hr; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $obs->upstream_elev; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $obs->downstream_elev; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $obs->avg_hourly_discharge; ?></td>
</tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the XML has 2 `<RESULTSET>` elements, the `RESULTSET->ROW` was just picking the first one.  So change that to `RESULTSET[1]->ROW` and you will get the data your after.

You also need to ensure that you use the same case for each element name...

```
<?php foreach ($xml->RESULTSET[1]->ROW as $obs) :?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $obs->OBS_DAY; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $obs->OBS_HR; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $obs->UPSTREAM_ELEV; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $obs->DOWNSTREAM_ELEV; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $obs->AVG_HOURLY_DISCHARGE; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: That worked to get the data!  Thanks.  After the data ended up in the table there is no spaces between it on the page.  How can I insert a space between columns with the data like I did in the table columns headers?

Comment: You use `<col>` in you headings, you probably should be using `<td>`

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!